# How can i use MongoDB with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, mongoose, google-cloud-functions

I want to use Cloud Functions for Firebase and MongoDB. The problem is I don't know how to connect my Mongo database with Cloud Functions. My database is deployed at matlab. 
I made this schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var patientSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required : true,
    },

    disease:{
        type: String,
        required : true, 
    },

    medication_provided: {
        type: String,
        required : true,
    },

    date : {
        type : Date,
    }
})

const patient = mongoose.model('patientInfo', patientSchema)
module.exports = patient
```

Then I require my schema in project index.js file, and export a function called getAllPatient.

```
const patient = require('../Patient')
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://patient:patient123@ds139869.mlab.com:39869/patient',{useMongoClient: true})
exports.getAllPatient = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    patient.find({}).then((data) => {
        response.send(data)
    })
})
```

but gives me an error that "Error: could not handle the request"

Comment: Could you edit your question to indicate where exactly are you seeing that error?

Comment: exports.getAllPatient = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    patient.find({}).then((data) => {
        response.send(data)
    })
})

Comment: I'm not asking about the code - you already showed that.  Are you seeing the error in the firebase console, or in the browser, or where else?

Comment: Just out of curiosity @DougStevenson isn't the error there because he can't make outbound requests?

Comment: That could be the problem, but that's not the error message I would expect to see.

Comment: I see, well, I think I'll leave you all to do your work. The other answer below sounds interesting.

Answer (score 5):

I was recently facing this type of error and found that firebase free plan doesn't allow the outbound connections from within the functions. If you need to call external http/tcp connections, you are required to be on the flame or blaze plan. see the screenshot attached below or see the section cloud functions -> outbound networking at this link [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to design the cloud function in a similar way shown in a link below:-

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js

I've tried with mongoose long time back and it was working fine and but it's slow because for every new request it's going to open the mongoose connection and serve you the data.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

**JUN 2023**

**TLDR; - Use Data API instead of connection.** [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api-resources/)

**[here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api/#std-label-data-api-get-started)** is How to enable data API & Get `MONGO_DATAAPI_URL` & `MONGO_DATAAPI_KEY` .

```js
exports.getAllPatient = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const data = {
    dataSource: dataSource,
    database: dbName,
    collection: collectionName,
  };

  const config = {
    method: "post",
    url: MONGO_DATAAPI_URL + "/action/find",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
      "api-key": MONGO_DATAAPI_KEY,
      Accept: "application/ejson",
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (resp) {
      response.send(resp.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      response.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

**Explanation** :

MongoDB allows a service called **Data API** to connect to MongoDB Atlas from any platform that supports HTTPS including

> - Web browsers
> - Web servers
> - CI/CD pipelines
> - **Serverless & Edge compute environments**
> - Mobile applications
> - Internet-Of-Things devices

For More :
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api-resources/
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/